# editing php.ini file via ssh doesn't take effect

Tags: apache, php

I use SSH to access my VPS server and login with root and edit the *php.ini* file, then save it. but after restarting apache , the changes get back so the changes don't take effect.

what should I do to solve this problem?

Using kloxo control panel and CentOS 5.8

Answer (score 0):

depends what your using.

this is the tutorial is used for plesk

http://www.linuxspy.info/704/how-to-enable-custom-php-ini-settings-for-particular-domain-in-plesk/

Comment: kloxo control panel, and CentOS